# Error rendering json file in ngFor

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am looping through a json file to display data in panels. But i am having some trouble controlling how to display the data appropriately. 
This is my json data that is returned from the services:

```
Object {Group1: Object, 
        Group2: Object}
```

The json file data sample:

```
{
  "Group1": {
      "name": "Group1List",
      "dataFields": [..],
      "dataQuery": {..},
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Group1",
      "content": {..}
    },
}
```

This is my services:

```
getGroupsData(){
        return this._http.get('...')
        .map((res:Response) => res.json())
    }
```

Component.ts:

```
 groups: Array<any> = [];
 getGroups(){
    this.groupService.getGroupsData().subscribe(
      data => this.groups = data;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div dnd-sortable-container [sortableData]="groups" [dropZones]="['container-dropZone']">
        <div class="col-sm3" *ngFor="let group of groups; let i = index" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i" [dragEnabled]="dragOperation">
            <div class="panel panel-primary" dnd-sortable-container [dropZones]="['widget-dropZone']">
                <div class="panel-heading"></div>
                <div class="panel-body"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

when i render the code i get an error in the console stating: `Error trying to diff '[object Object]'`  in the heading i would like to add `Group1` and then in the body i will display different parts from the json.

What is the source of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*ngFor` requires an array [], and you are passing an object

Your sample has unnecessary nested level, flat is always better

Your json should look like this

```
[
   {
     "name": "Group1List",
     "dataFields": [..],
     "dataQuery": {..},
     "id": 1,
     "title": "Group1",
     "content": {..}
   },
   {
     "name": "Group2List",
     "dataFields": [..],
     "dataQuery": {..},
     "id": 2,
     "title": "Group2",
     "content": {..}
   },
   // ....
]
```

**Update:**

If you have no control over your json scheme, try to flatten it here

```
getGroupsData(){
    return this._http.get('...')
    .map((res:Response) => res.json())
    .map((obj) => Object.keys(obj).map((key)=>{ return obj[key]})
}
```

or implement a pipe that iterate over object properties

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push(key);
    }
    return keys;
  }
}
```

and use it like this

```
<div *ngFor="let group of groups | keys; let i = index">

</div>
```

Comment: I agree with you but  i can't change the json format and has remain as i have it.

Comment: so i don't get the error when rendering but when i try to print data from json i get an undefined error. `{{group[i].title}}`

Comment: @bluePearl `group.title` straight away, group is an object here not an array

Comment: or `{{groups[i].title}}`

Comment: what if in my dataQuery for Group1 i have `uri: "json file link"` do i have to do something for it to load json for that link?

Comment: make another http request for that uri

Comment: can i add the new http request within the existing request in the `getGroupsData`?

Comment: Yes you can make a function that has a uri parameter and use it from the template 'getDataQuery(group.dataQuery)'

Answer (score 1):

`*ngFor` requires an array, but it looks like you are passing it an object.

If you cannot change the JSON response, and you know the names of the groups beforehand, you can place the objects in an array:

`this.groups = [data.Group1, data.Group2, // etc]`

Answer (score 0):

Change your component to:

```
groups: Array<any> = [];
 getGroups(){
    this.groupService.getGroupsData().subscribe(
      data => this.groups = data.Group1.dataFields;
  }
```

**Why?**

Because,  you want your `groups` component property to be an array.
So, in your subscribe handler, `data` will refer to the entire JSON object, and you only care about the `Group1` property of your results.

Comment: i would like for the ngFor loop to go through Group1, Group2, Group3 as i have multiple groups. With your code does that mean i will have to do separate calls for `data =>this.groups = data.Groups2...` for each group?